# Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly. We cannot execute /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/bin/java

Tags: java, environment-variables

if i'm executing the `mvn -version` commnad  its giving me the exact verison of mvn.

But when i'm trying to execute the same command with `sudo mvn -version`

Its throwing me the above error.

my .bash_profile

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:$PATH
export M2_HOME=/Users/ta302118/Softwares/apache-maven-3.0.5
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin
```

and if tried to execute below command i'm getting same error

```
sudo mvn spring-boot:run  

Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/bin/java
```

Can anyone please help on this .

Comment: Most likely the security policy does not allow the JAVA_HOME environment variable to be passed on to the sudo environment.

Answer (score 3):

In your .bash_profile you define JAVA in PATH twice.
Once it is in JAVA_HOME/jre/bin
and once it is JAVA_HOME/bin.

Comment: You are placing question inside your answer. I know you can't do it yet, but you'll use comments for anything that is unclear related to question you are answering (comments on question).